# Python - TKinter "times out"

Tags: python, tkinter, timeout

This is my first post on stackoverflow but I have been using the answers for some time now as I've hit bumps in the code road. The dark day has come where I can't seem to find the answer so please let me know if you can help.

The program is pretty simple I'm using Tkinter to create a widget that just sits on my desktop and tells me how many files are in specific folders. It seems to work pretty well for about 10 minutes and then stops working. It doesn't crash or ping up an error message it just freezes until I realise that somethings wrong and then when I go to click on it or close it down it says it has stopped working.

Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time
import os
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Style


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.clock = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.clock.pack()


        # start the clock "ticking"
        self.update_clock()


    def update_clock(self):

        ptc = len(os.listdir("Folder Dir"))
        if ptc != 0:
            label1 = Label(self, text="Pre TC", fg="red")
        else:
            label1 = Label(self, text="Pre TC")
        label1.place(x=0, y=0)
        if ptc != 0:
            label2 = Label(self, text=ptc, fg="red")
        else:
            label2 = Label(self, text=ptc)
        label2.place(x=90, y=0)


        pp = len(os.listdir("Folder Dir"))
        if pp != 0:
            label3 = Label(self, text="PP", fg="red")
        else:
            label3 = Label(self, text="PP")
        label3.place(x=0, y=65)
        if pp != 0:
            label4 = Label(self, text=pp, fg="red")
        else:
            label4 = Label(self, text=pp)
        label4.place(x=90, y=65)



        stc = len(os.listdir("Folder Dir"))
        if stc != 0:
            label5 = Label(self, text="Super TC", fg="red")
        else:
            label5 = Label(self, text="Super TC")
        label5.place(x=0, y=150)
        if stc!= 0:     
            label6 = Label(self, text=stc, fg="red")
        else:
            label6 = Label(self, text=stc)
        label6.place(x=90, y=150)



        wff = len(os.listdir("Folder Dir"))
        if wff != 0:
            label7 = Label(self, text="WIN FF", fg="red")
        else:
            label7 = Label(self, text="WIN FF")
        label7.place(x=0, y=230)

        if wff != 0:
            label8 = Label(self, text=wff, fg="red")
        else:
            label8 = Label(self, text=wff)
        label8.place(x=90, y=230)



        wa = len(os.listdir("Folder Dir"))
        if wa != 0:
            label9 = Label(self, text="Wave Agent", fg="red")
        else:
            label9 = Label(self, text="Wave Agent")
        label9.place(x=0, y=315)
        if wa != 0:
            label10 = Label(self, text=wa, fg="red")
        else:
            label10 = Label(self, text=wa)
        label10.place(x=90, y=315)



        bwf = len(os.listdir("Folder Dir"))
        if bwf != 0:
            label11 = Label(self, text="BWF", fg="red")
        else:
            label11 = Label(self, text="BWF")
        label11.place(x=0, y=395)
        if bwf != 0:
            label12 = Label(self, text=bwf, fg="red")
        else:
            label12 = Label(self, text=bwf)
        label12.place(x=90, y=395)



        swi = len(os.listdir("Folder Dir"))
        if swi != 0:
            label13 = Label(self, text="Switch", fg="red")
        else:
            label13 = Label(self, text="Switch")
        label13.place(x=0, y=480)
        if swi != 0:
            label14 = Label(self, text=swi, fg="red")
        else:
            label14 = Label(self, text=swi)
        label14.place(x=90, y=480)

        # call this function again in one second
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)

def main():
    app = SampleApp()
    app.title('Counter')
    app.geometry("50x510+1000+8")
    app.mainloop()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

All help would be really apprciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're creating 14 new widgets every second, but you never destroy any of the old ones. After ten minutes of this, you've got a window that has to keep track of 8,400 elements, which I expect would bog it down considerably.

I see two solutions:

- `.destroy()` all previous widgets before you create more.
- create 14 widgets exactly once at the beginning of the program, then `.config` them to change their text during every `update_clock` call.

Comment: so are the new widgets being created in the background or something? when you run the program you can't see new windows popping up

Comment: The new widgets appear in the same window as the old widgets. The new widgets are positioned identically to the old ones, and appear on top of them, so the old ones are no longer visible. But they're still there.

Comment: Ahh that makes a ton of sense! Just wanna say thanks for the quick reply! I think I've probably got enough to go on from your answer to look up any other info I need so thanks!